# React implicit mapping mechanism

Tags: reactjs

I am going through the tutorial:

https://www.robinwieruch.de/gentle-introduction-higher-order-components/

And they have such kind of statements:

```
const withTodosNull = (Component) => (props) =>
  !props.todos
    ? null
    : <Component { ...props } />
```

As I understand `Component` is passed to the function, then its `props` get implicitly taken and fed into the return function. I do not understand how the `React` is doing that. I would honestly expect something like `(Component) => (Component.props)`. What is the mechanism for this? Is it mapped correctly only if we supply the argument as `props` or we can supply any name? Is there a specific name for such implicit assignment?

> Update

Maybe I was not clear enough, but what I am really interested in is from where `props` appear in the inner function if they are not passed to the previous, outer, function. I understand how the HOCs work, how to think about them, but this moment is very unclear and what in `React` is doing that? Is there some kind of an `engine` running behind the scenes, idk...

Answer (score 2):

It will be probably easier to understand if we rewrite arrow functions using classic `function()`:

```
function withTodosNull(Component) {
   return function(props) {
      if (!props.todos) {
         return null;
      }

      return <Component {...props} />;
   }
}
```

The inner unnamed function is a functional component. It takes properties and renders either as `null` or as `Component`.

The outer function is something called high-order-component (HoC). It is a function, that wraps a component and returns a new component.

There is no connection between `Component` and `props`. They are only parameters of two different functions.

Specifically, when you call:

```
class MyComponent: React.Component {
}

const myComponentWithTodosNull = withTodosNull(MyComponent);
```

it is the same as writing:

```
const myComponentWithTodosNull = props => {
  if (!props.todos) {
    return null;
  }

  return <MyComponent {...props} />;
}
```

Comment: I understand that and that is why it is very vague: it should not happen because we are passing in a `Component` and not `props`, so there is some kind of implicit assignment of `props` to the relevant scope is going on which I do not understand

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko Try to look at the last example I have given again. A functional component is a function with `props` as a parameter. A HoC is a function that returns a functional component.

Comment: So, you mean passing a `Component` is equivalent to passing `(props) => { ... }`, that it is the same thing and `Component` is just such a function? That I did not know. Is it always the case that `React` components have such a structure (by definition)?

Answer (score 2):

This technique is called [higher-order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) (HOCs) and is a way of extending components with some extra functionality.

It might look easier at first if you rewrite it using regular functions instead of arrow functions:

```
function withTodosNull(Component) {
  return function(props) {
    if (!props.todos) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return <Component {...props} />
    }
  }
}
```

`withTodosNull` takes in a component and returns a new component. If this new component that is returned gets a `todos` prop, the component passed into the HOC will be rendered with all the props. If `todos` is not given as a prop, `null` will be rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Higher-Order Components are functions that "enhance" components passed as a parameter. To understand where the props are coming from let's see what would it look like to use such component.

There's our basic component, which will be passed to the HoC:

```
function TodoList(props) {
  return (
    <div>We have {props.todos.length} tasks to do!</div>
  );
}
```

And now, we can use our HoC to create new "enhanced" component, which prevents displaying this message, when there aren't any tasks left:

```
const EnhancedTodoList = withTodosNull(TodoList);
```

Then we can use this new component, to render the message (or not, if there aren't any tasks):

```
<EnhancedTodoList todos={someTodos} />
```

As you can see, `EnhancedTodoList` is the first component, which gets `todos`. Then it decides if props should be passed to `TodoList`, or should it return `null`, when there aren't any todos.

Todos are passed explicitly from the component which renders the HoC. `EnhancedTodoList` acts just like a filter for `TodoList`.

Comment: This answer is kind of closest to what I was asking, but still not that

Comment: I've read your update. Take a look at definition of `withTodosNull`, there's a line which renders wrapped component: `<Component { ...props } />`. Expression `{...props}` means that all props passed to `withTodosNull` are spread (passed) to wrapped component (in my example: `TodoList`). This is how the `TodoList` gets all the props from `EnhancedTodoList`.

Comment: The tutorial that I gave link to has such statements: `const TodoListWithNull = withTodosNull(TodoList)`. Only `Component` is passed. Then inside `withTodosNull` we somehow access `props` that were not passed to the function.